# Error:(66, 27) error: constructor LineData in class LineData cannot be applied to given types; required: ILineDataSet[] found: String[],

Tags: android-studio

I was following the example on youtube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNeE9DJoOMY&t=614s, Creating a Line Graph with multiple data sets in Android Studio. I believe the code is correct... but still getting error: constuctor LineData error.. Another post on stackoverflow suggested that maybe the MPandroidChart library may have changed requiring a different input?  The full error is:

```
Error:(66, 27) error: constructor LineData in class LineData cannot be applied to given types;
required: ILineDataSet[]
found: String[],LineDataSet
reason: varargs mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to ILineDataSet
```

Here is my main code:

```
package com.example.rj.linegraph1;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LineChart lineChart;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.lineChart);

        ArrayList<String> xAXIS = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yAXISsin = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yAXIScos = new ArrayList<>();

        double x = 0;
        int numDataPoints = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++) {
            float sinFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.sin(x)));
            float cosFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.cos(x)));
            x = x + 0.1;
            yAXISsin.add(new Entry(sinFunction,i));
            yAXIScos.add(new Entry(cosFunction,i));

            xAXIS.add(i, String.valueOf(x));


        }

        String[] xaxis = new String[xAXIS.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < xAXIS.size(); i++) {
            xaxis[i] = xAXIS.get(i).toString();



        }

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(yAXIScos,"cos");
        lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(false);
        lineDataSet1.setColors(Color.BLUE);
        LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(yAXISsin,"sin");
        lineDataSet2.setDrawCircles(false);
        lineDataSet2.setColors(Color.RED);

        lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
        lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

        lineChart.setData(new LineData(xaxis,lineDataSets));
        lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(65f);





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how the library requires you to do it now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++) {
        float sinFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.sin(x)));
        float cosFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.cos(x)));
        x = x + 0.1;
        yAXISsin.add(new Entry(x, sinFunction));
        yAXIScos.add(new Entry(x, cosFunction));

        //dont use strings anymore
        //xAXIS.add(i, String.valueOf(x));
    }
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(yAXIScos,"cos");
    LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(yAXISsin,"sin");

    lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(false);
    lineDataSet1.setColors(Color.RED);
    lineDataSet2.setDrawCircles(false);
    lineDataSet2.setColors(Color.BLUE);

    lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
    lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

    lineChart.setData(new LineData(lineDataSets));
    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(65f);
```

Pretty sure it's something like that. You no longer add the X-Axis values like before. Now the X-Axis values just get added as Entry's.

Let me know if this works. I didn't try it myself.

Comment: Thanks Again, I had to modify the code a little to get it to run.  The add( new Entry ... expected to have x be a float and not a double, so I change it to a float.  The graph loaded on to the android device, but it was an empty graph. It had graticule lines but no red or blue Sin or Cos traces on it.  I kind of looked through the code to try to make 'x' the same as the other varibles, but I could not find anything else..

Comment: double xi = 0;
        
            float sinFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.sin(xi)));
            float cosFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.cos(xi)));
            float x = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(xi + 0.1));
            yAXISsin.add(new Entry(x, sinFunction));
            yAXIScos.add(new Entry(x, cosFunction));

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you need 'x' to be a double for the math operations but you need to convert it to a float for each Entry.

I also added some logs in here so you can debug it might easily.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//added for debugging
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

LineChart lineChart;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.lineChart);

    ArrayList<Entry> yAXISsin = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yAXIScos = new ArrayList<>();

double x = 0.0;
int numDataPoints = 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++) {
    float sinFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.sin(x)));
    float cosFunction = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.cos(x)));
    x = x + 0.1;
    float xEntry = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(x));
    yAXISsin.add(new Entry(xEntry, sinFunction));
    yAXIScos.add(new Entry(xEntry, cosFunction));

    Log.d(TAG, "Populating Arrays with Data: yAXISsin = " + sinFunction);
    Log.d(TAG, "Populating Arrays with Data: yAXIScos = " + cosFunction);
    Log.d(TAG, "Populating Arrays with Data: xEntry = " + xEntry);

}
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(yAXIScos,"cos");
LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(yAXISsin,"sin");

lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(false);
lineDataSet1.setColors(Color.RED);
lineDataSet2.setDrawCircles(false);
lineDataSet2.setColors(Color.BLUE);

lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

lineChart.setData(new LineData(lineDataSets));
lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(65f);

//can also try calling invalidate() to refresh the graph
lineChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks again, It works perfectly now. I guess you can not do math operations inside the .valueOf() function?  It is really too bad that they did not keep the MPandoid library backwards compatible.  Thanks a milliion.. Java is so much different than c or fortran... You are Awsome.